# What is result from cut fill operation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d, 3d-analyst, volume

I calculate volume of lake from rasters with cut fill tools. I got a result and I don't know what is right result. In the table are two columns  **COUNT** and **VOLUME**  maybe I have to count multiply volume or volume is the final volume of lake?

https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t34.0-12/1058703_1021925644496509_333857375_n.jpg?oh=ee2b652172d28e4dc92986b5a3c46b20&oe=56763999

Answer (score 3):

The negative volume is the amount of dirt you have used to fill the hole in projection units and your chosen z unit. In your case it is the amount of fill needed to fill the lake. So if x y z are meters it would be meters cubed.

From esri help.

"The attribute table of the output raster presents the changes in the surface volumes following the cut/fill operation. Positive values for the volume difference indicate regions of the before raster surface that have been cut (material removed). Negative values indicate areas that have been filled (material added)."

No the count should not be multiplied by volume. The count is related to the value. That is, how many of this value exist.